# How to dynamically attach retry advice on an http outbound gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Hey i have an http outbound gateway which i've attached a retry advice to:

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway(spelParser.parseExpression("headers." + HeaderKeys.TARGET_ENDPOINT))
            .extractPayload(true)
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
            .expectedResponseType(String.class)
            .requestFactory(requestFactory())
            .get()
        , httpOutboundEndpointSpec())
```

The `httpOutboundEndpointSpec`:

```
@Bean 
public Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler>> httpOutboundEndpointSpec() {
    return new Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(GenericEndpointSpec<HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler> spec) {
            spec.advice(context.getBean("lengthy", RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.class));
            spec.requiresReply(true);
        }
    };
}
```

Is there a way to hook up the advice dynamically depending on the contents of the message? Different clients now need different intervals of backoff. I could write one outbound gateway per client with a different retry advice each, but that would make a lot of gateways.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution would be a [custom advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#custom-advice) that has a set of `RetryTemplate`s and uses one of them based on the message.

You could base your advice on the  and choose which retry template to use.